# How to combine results from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have table 1 like this:

[image]

and table 2:

[image]

and result should be like this:

[image: Result]

I want to combine results from 2 tables above. How can I do it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @PeterSmith I want to get the result like this: http://res.cloudinary.com/luanvne/image/upload/v1467540559/3_rf1xyp.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seems like they have a relation, so `CROSS JOIN` is what you need:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t
CROSS JOIN Table2 s
```

**EDIT:** Use `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT tt.loaiphong,ss.col1,ss.col2........
FROM (SELECT t.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as rnk FROM Table1 t) tt
INNER JOIN(SELECT s.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as rnk FROM Table2 s) ss
 ON(tt.rnk = ss.rnk)
```

If you are intrested of all records from both table, not only matched rows, then change the `INNER JOIN` to `FULL OUTER JOIN` .

Comment: It seems not correct, I get 9 rows. http://res.cloudinary.com/luanvne/image/upload/v1467540765/4_jz0yge.jpg 
 I want to get the result like this: http://res.cloudinary.com/luanvne/image/upload/v1467540559/3_rf1xyp.jpg

Comment: Why  does `DLX` joined to  the first row? Why `SUI` to the second? How am I supposed to do that without a relation? @ZaneKey

Comment: I add photos of result above. Could you see and imagine what result I want to get?

Comment: You are not listening to me, WHY DOES `DLX` CONNECTS TO THE FIRST ROW?! Why not the second one???

Comment: I simple want to comebine  from table 1 and 2 and get new table with 3 rows like this: http://res.cloudinary.com/luanvne/image/upload/v1467540559/3_rf1xyp.jpg
It does not matter DLX connects to the first row or the second.

Comment: @ZaneKey, a table is an unordered set of rows so you must define exactly what you mean by the "first", "second", or "third" row.  The order of rows without an `ORDER BY` is by happenstance and could change during each query execution.  In short, you must either have another column to define the 1-to-1 relationship or a column to derive ordering to assign a row number.  I see neither here.

Comment: It's OK, didn't notice that typo:) Thanks. @shA.t

Comment: Maybe make a little more sense, but it's not necessarily the requirement .. I've added a note about it.

Comment: @sagi thanks for your help, but still have a small problem: it have 2 columns rnk like this:
http://res.cloudinary.com/luanvne/image/upload/v1467557021/5_feouu9.jpg
I don't want 2 columns rnk appear at the table.

Comment: @ZaneKey don't select them then.

Comment: @ZaneKey Come on.. your pushing it, make some efforts! choose only the columns you want